# Tagging issues when selecting from the list

Tags: bug, tags

I have found this on several SE sites, so I'm not sure what might be causing it, but sometimes when I start typing in a tag, like "dar" for [dark-souls-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-souls-2), I click on it in the list, but nothing happens. I'm just left with "dar" still in the text box.

If I then submit the question, it adds the bogus tag. Does anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce this is by clicking on the space between tags, which closes the list but does not select any tag. You can avoid this by clicking on the tag or tag description.

If you really want to avoid this in general, just proofread your question before posting, which is probably a good idea anyway.